# mySQL corruption "Cannot add foreign key constraint" trying to CREATE table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, corruption

EDIT This is a corrupt mySQL DB problem. Pls see "EDIT:" below

Trying to add a table called client to a new mySQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
    `id`            INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `person_id`     INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Every time I get: `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

I have looked at all the reserved word lists I can find. None of them seem to have "client".

I can use "clients" (but do not like having table as plurals -0 all the others are singular), "clientxxx" etc. I REALLY want to use "client". Is there a way round this? It is important that they are clients not patients.

PS I have deleted all other tables from the DB this still will not fly.

PPS Although not listed `CLIENT` ***is*** a ****** reserved word in SQL in reality (or at least HeidiSQL lists it. Is there any way around it? (I think I know the answer to that one). And why the heck is it not in the mySQL reserved words list?

***EDIT:*** OK dropped old DB. Tried with a DB called testxxx and worked fine. Tried to rename DB to old name = betadb01 and got:

`Database "betadb01" exists. but it does not contain objects with the same names as in "testxxx", so it's uncritical to move everything. Move all objects to "betadb01"?`

... said yes and then got `SQL error (1025) ... errno 150 - foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

I have run all the repair options in HeidiSQL. Looking through the repair and analysis logs the DB in question is nowhere to be seen. I can pretty easily rename the DB and get past the problem but this is a bit nervous making. Any ideas how I can clean out this problem? Complete reinstall of mySQL after exporting my other databases???

Comment: This works fine when I try it, so it's not an issue with the name of the table.

Comment: Is there any relation between this table and `Person` table, if yes remove `Default '0'`

Comment: Your structure is not an issue i tried twice working fine ....

Comment: Tried it in Heidi and myPHP. Heidi lists `CLIENT` in its list of SQL words. There is nothing in the table at all. May try and drop and recreate. Thanks for the thoughts guys.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I had created a table and build some pk-fk relationship, it was crashed and that table is gone suddenly by no reasons...it just disappear from the database???? Then I recreate the table with the same errors as your. I have google the problem but cannot find the answer too. In my conclusion, mysql is too unreliable if you plan to use it as critical business application database.